# Java socket , client and server

Tags: java, jsp, sockets, client

I want to do a socket connection for client and server to display the list of files. but below code is not taking any input from server or giving output to client. Please help.

Server

```
package javaapplicationthread;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;



public class zs {
  public static int reads,red;  
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
            int flg=0;

           try{while(true){ 
               ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1312);
           Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

                         BufferedReader bufferedReader;
       PrintWriter outk=new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);

       bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

       String inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
       System.out.println("input is"+ inputLine);
       outk.write("abc");

         File inputFolder = new File(inputLine);
    System.out.println("control is being sent to traverse");
         traverse(inputFolder, "");

    }
           }            
       catch (IOException ex) {
                  System.out.println("my exception is"+ex)
            System.out.println(leftIndent + parentNode.getName());
        }

    }}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Posting your code here and saying "it doesn't work" is not a valid question.

Comment: Brian Roach -where  did i said it dosent work? it is not giving any errors and if i run the traverse(File parentNode, String leftIndent) function separtly, it is working.. but when i made it using socket everything got blocked

Comment: You need to close your sockets, in both server and client, and you need to create the `ServerSocket` once, not once per loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the client, when you do `redd = b.readLine();` you are asking to read an entire line. But in the server you haven't sent an entire line: you've only asked it to write three characters:

```
outk.write("abc");
```

None of those three characters is actually sent, however, because the PrintWriter buffers them temporarily. To fix it, change that line to:

```
outk.println("abc");
```

Or:

```
outk.write("abc\n");
outk.flush();
```

After that change, the client successfully displays: `result is abc`.

> it is not giving any errors

They're both giving errors... The client throws an exception when the readLine call fails. The server throws an exception when it begins the next iteration of the `while(true)` loop and tries to recreate the socket it is still using. You probably want to move the creation of the ServerSocket outside the while loop.

Comment: Your final paragraph is incorrect. First the server fails, trying to *bind* a *new* `ServerSocket` to the *port* it is already using, which causes it to exit, which resets the connection, which causes readLine() to fail and throw a `SocketException.`